# Ansible: creating variables from JSON response

Tags: json, ansible

I am struggling on understanding how to get the response from one uri call to pass to another. I am creating a playbook for my storage system. It requires a SessionKey for all REST calls passed in a custom header "X-HP3PAR-WSAPI-SessionKey"

The initial authentication REST call works succeeds and I see the SessionKey. I am unable to get the SessionKey to be passed to the subsequent call.

Any suggestions?

```
---
- name: Connect to 3par
  hosts: localhost
  become: no

  vars:
    auth_3par_user: "3paruser"
    auth_3par_password: "3parpass"
    ip_address_3par: 1.1.1.1
    rest_api_url_3par: "https://{{ ip_address_3par }}:8080/api/v1"

  tasks:
    - name: check if 3par WSAPI is running
      uri:
        url: "{{ rest_api_url_3par }}/credentials"
        force_basic_auth: yes
        method: POST
        HEADER_Content-Type: application/json
        body_format: json
        body: "{ 'user': '{{ auth_3par_user }}', 'password': '{{ auth_3par_password }}' }"
        status_code: 201
        return_content: yes
        validate_certs: no
      register: output

    - name: Parsing key
      debug:
        msg: "{{ output.json.key }}"

    - name: GET 3par volumes
      uri:
        url: "{{ rest_api_url_3par }}/volumes"
        method: GET
        HEADER_Content-Type: "application/json"
        headers:
          "X-HP3PAR-WSAPI-SessionKey": "{{ output.json.key }}"
        status_code: 200
        return_content: yes
        validate_certs: no
      register: volume_output

    - name: Parsing Volumes GET
      debug:
        var={{ volume_output.stdout | from_json }}
```

---

```
TASK [Parsing key]     *************************************************************
task path: /home/chris/ansible/ansible_3par/playbooks/connect_3par.yml:26
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "0-f150f34f975693b3c95efa84b13bd605-00cc315a"
}

TASK [check if 3par WSAPI is running] ******************************************
task path: /home/chris/ansible/ansible_3par/playbooks/connect_3par.yml:30
ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: chris
127.0.0.1 EXEC ( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1513213268.76-220322452758647 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1513213268.76-220322452758647 )" )
127.0.0.1 PUT /tmp/tmpgOtWjh TO /home/chris/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1513213268.76-220322452758647/uri
127.0.0.1 EXEC LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/chris/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1513213268.76-220322452758647/uri; rm -rf "/home/chris/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1513213268.76-220322452758647/" > /dev/null 2>&1
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "{\"code\":6,\"desc\":\"invalid session key\"}",
```

Ansible version 2.0.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing old and new syntax for headers in `uri` module.

And as you use an antiquated Ansible 2.0 version, `headers` parameter is completely ignored.

Upgrade to the current Ansible version.

---

For reference:

- if you use Ansible < 2.1 define all headers using `HEADER_*`,
- if you use Ansible >= 2.1 define all headers under `headers`.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the corrected, functional code for reference after fixing headers and updating Ansible to latest version.

```
---
- name: Connect to 3par
  hosts: localhost
  become: no

  vars:
    auth_3par_user: "3paruser"
    auth_3par_password: "3parpass"
    ip_address_3par: 1.1.1.1
    rest_api_url_3par: "https://{{ ip_address_3par }}:8080/api/v1"

  tasks:
    - name: check if 3par WSAPI is running
      uri:
        url: "{{ rest_api_url_3par }}/credentials"
        method: POST
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
        body_format: json
        body: "{ 'user': '{{ auth_3par_user }}', 'password': '{{ auth_3par_password }}' }"
        status_code: 201
        return_content: yes
        validate_certs: no
      register: output

    - name: Parsing key
      debug:
        msg: "{{ output.json.key }}"

    - name: GET 3par volumes
      uri:
        url: "{{ rest_api_url_3par }}/volumes"
        method: GET
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          X-HP3PAR-WSAPI-SessionKey: "{{ output.json.key }}"
          Accept: "application/json"
        status_code: 200
        return_content: yes
        validate_certs: no
      register: volume_output

    - name: Parsing Volumes GET
      debug:
        msg: "{{ volume_output }}"enter code here
```